# Change array values depending on selections in listbox on a userform

Tags: vba, excel

I want to be able to change array values from my sub that runs a userform. How do I go about doing this?

Here is an example of what I have:

```
A = [25, 50, 75, 100]
UserForm1.Show
```

UserForm1 contains a listbox with options 1, 2 or 3.
By selecting "1", "2,", "3", or multiple combinations of them I want to change the value of A accordingly.

```
If "1" is selected Then
A(0) = 10
If "2" is selected Then
A(1) = 0
If "3" is selected Then
A(2) = 1000
```

How would I make this happen? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "1" will always `=True`. Same for "2" and "3", etc. Do you mean if the item is *selected* in the listbox?

Comment: Yes if they are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tested in a `ListBox_AfterUpdate()` event. Get a handle on the `ListBox` object (assigned to variable `lb`) then iterate the items in the `lb.List`, checking if each is selected. If selected, then assign a positional value to the array `A`.

The array `A` is declared as a module/user-form scoped variable here, and assigned default/initial values during the form's `_Initialize` event. Those values are then changed if the user makes a selection(s) in the ListBox.

```
Option Explicit
Dim A()
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Assigns initial values to your array:
A = Array(25, 50, 75, 100)
'Assigns the default ListBox items:
Me.ListBox1.List = Array("1", "2", "3")
End Sub
Private Sub ListBox1_AfterUpdate()
Dim lb As MSForms.ListBox
Dim i As Long, v As Long
Set lb = Me.ListBox1 '# Modify as needed
For i = 0 To lb.ListCount - 1
    If lb.Selected(i) Then
        Select Case lb.List(i)
            Case "1"
                v = 10
            Case "2"
                v = 0
            Case "3"
                v = 1000
        End Select
        'confirm prev & new values for array:
        MsgBox (A(i) & " will be changed to: " & v)
        A(i) = v
        'Confirm the value in array has changed
        MsgBox (A(i))
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Depending on where/when you initialize the `A` array, you could modify this and invoke it from the `ListBox_Change` or `ListBox_AfterUpdate` event, or call it from another control's event procedure as needed.

Comment: This looks like just what I need. Would I put this code in the sub produced from double clicking the listbox? How do I call A array so its data can be altered?

Comment: *Where* you would put it depends on what you're trying to do. I can't answer that for you. I don't understand your second question. Do you understand variable *scope* in VBA? If not, please research it and use appropriate scope. Probably you want a public variable in the UserForm module, but again, that depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you want to call this code from the ListBox, I would suggest the `Change` or `AfterUpdate` event, probably not the `Click` event.